# Upload to AWS S3 failing

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file from my Wordpress application to a S3 bucket by Ajax:
Somehow, I don't get an answer and the script fails with a 500 error when applying the 'putObject' method.

**app/ajax.php**

```
require_once 's3/start.php'
//wp_die(var_dump($s3)); Seems to be fine
$upload = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
    'Key' => 'video,
    'Body'   => fopen( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r' ),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
]);
if ($upload) {
    wp_die('Uploaded');
} else {
    wp_die('Upload Error');
}
```

**app/s3/start.php**

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
$config = require('config.php');
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'key'       =>  $config['s3']['key'],
    'secret'    =>  $config['s3']['secret'],
    'region'    =>  $config['s3']['region'],
    'version'   =>  'latest',
]);
```

**app/s3/aws**

```
Latest version of the official AWS SDK for PHP
```

**SOLUTION**
The credentials in app/start.php where not assigned correctly when initialising the $s3 object. That's how it must look like

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory([
'region'    =>  $config['s3']['region'],
'version'   =>  'latest',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => $config['s3']['key'],
    'secret' => $config['s3']['secret']
]
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload a file, you should use `SourceFile` instead of `Body`.

Example code:

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'       => $bucket,
        'Key'          => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        'Metadata'     => array(    
            'param1' => 'value 1',
            'param2' => 'value 2'
        )
    ));
```

More info from here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html

Comment: Just tried that, but still not working.
Testing with wp_die() I get the following result:
$bucket => the correct bucket name,
$key => the correct key name,
$filepath => '/tmp/phpNKgE0e'

Comment: iI've just inspected the objects methods by var_dump(get_class_methods($s3)) and there is no putObject method

Comment: Ah - please do two things 1) can you print out all errors using `ini_set()` and `error_reporting()`?. It will definitely help you. 2) Your client connection seems invalid as well, `key` and `secret` are usually nested inside `credentials`. Check out this doc, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html, for the credential part.

Comment: You are awesome. The credentials it was, seems like I didn't assign them correctly, I've just updated the post. Thanks a lot!